# Following a topic in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, topics

i have a list of topics in my visualforce page.i get topics list using soql query

```
Select Id,Name,TalkingAbout,Description from Topic
```

i want to show a follow button in that when it will be clicked current user will start following that topic.Is it possible in visualforce and apex or not .Please guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EntitySubscription](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm) to follow records including Topics

When you click on the Follow button, from your controller action method, create/insert an EntitySubscription record by setting the **ParentId** to the TopicId and **SubscriberId** to the userId.

you can also refer the Recipie 5 in this [Chatter Recipie](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes) article from salesforce for a code sample.